# How to check whether list is present inside list in the java

Tags: java

A TreeSet containing a list and containing custom comparator. I want to check whether the list is present inside the list but this code is giving me the wrong answer. Can anybody resolve this issue with a proper explanation or how to make modify the treeset for getting the correct answer,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //Creating TreeSet
        TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>> H = new TreeSet<ArrayList<Integer>>(new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>() {

//Implementing the comparotor
            @Override
            public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size()); ++i) {
                    //Checking the order of the number 
                    if (o1.get(i) < o2.get(i)) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (o1.get(i) > o2.get(i)) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
                if (o1.size() == o2.size()) {
                    return 0;
                }
                if (o1.size() < o2.size()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;

            }
        });
        
 ArrayList<Integer>A=new ArrayList<>();
 A.add(1);
 A.add(2);
 A.add(3);
 //Inserting the list in the treeset
 H.add(A);

 ArrayList<Integer>B=new ArrayList<>();
 B.add(1);
 B.add(2);
 B.add(3);
 B.add(4);
 System.out.println(H.contains(B));  //This line is giving true



    }
```

Comment: You always return on the first iteration of the for loop.

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: Note that [Arrays.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#compare(T%5B%5D,T%5B%5D)) already does this.  No need to reinvent it.  Repeatedly converting Lists to arrays has the potential to hurt performance, so I would just use `new TreeSet<int[]>(Arrays::compare)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop never executes for more than one iteration: all three branches of the conditional contain a `return` statement.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size()); ++i) {
    //Checking the order of the number 
    if (o1.get(i) < o2.get(i)) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1.get(i) > o2.get(i)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So, all you are doing is comparing the first elements of the two lists.

Remove the `return 0;` in the final case.

You may instead find it neater to write the comparator body as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size()); ++i) {
  int cmp = Integer.compare(o1.get(i), o2.get(i));
  if (cmp != 0) {
    return cmp;
  }
}
return Integer.compare(o1.size(), o2.size());
```

---

In terms of writing your existing code as suggested ("you may find it neater"), the original code is equivalent to:

```
if (!o1.isEmpty() && !o2.isEmpty()) {
  return Integer.compare(o1.get(0), o2.get(0));
}
return Integer.compare(o1.size(), o2.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator is broken. Test it separately: Forget the TreeSet, just make `List<Integer>` objects with test data and run `comparator.compare(a, b)` and debug this. Your loop that loops through all indices that both lists share **always returns**, meaning, it never really loops: It runs once, on the first number (Which in your example is `1` for both of the lists), and returns a value.

Presumably, you do **NOT** want to `return 0` if the values are equal, instead, `continue;`. Or just let the for loop run to its end brace naturally (so two ifs: If smaller, return -1. If larger, return +1. That's it - the remaining case (they are equal) will loop.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here lies on the comparator. I'm gonna break down why this does not work:
First block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(o1.size(), o2.size()); ++i) {
                //Checking the order of the number 
                if (o1.get(i) < o2.get(i)) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.get(i) > o2.get(i)) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
```

Here, you have some problems:

1. If the lists are not the same size, you don't care. You iterate through the minimum length, which is not correct. If the length of the arrays are different, you should just return 0, as they can't be equal being different size.
2. Second, even if they were the same size, you are giving a `return` after checking the first item. So, if two arrays are not the same, but their first item is the same, you will return true (what is actually happening in your code)

So, what I would say is implementing the following conditions:

1. Check if length are equal
2. If length is not equal, return -1
3. If length is equal, then iterate through the list and compare each number. If the number is not equal, we finish iterating as we know they're not equal anymore. If the number is equal, keep comparing. You will return true when you reach the end of the list and all elements are equal.

Example code:

```
public int compare(ArrayList<Integer> o1, ArrayList<Integer> o2) {

            // length of the arrays is not equal
            if (o1.size() != o2.size()) {
                return -1;
            } else 
            // length is equal, so continue
            {
                Boolean equal = true;
                // we iterate through the array length while the elements are equal
                for (int i = 0; i < o1.size() && equal; ++i) {
                    if (o1.get(i) != o2.get(i)) {
                        equal = false;
                    }
                }
                // if all elements were equal, return 0. And we return -1 otherwise
                if equal {
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return -1
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: "If the length of the arrays are different, you should just return 0, as they can't be equal being different size." No: you should _definitely_ not return 0 if they are different lengths, because they aren't equal. Think about strings: you can compare "a" to "ab": different lengths, clearly not equal. OP is (attempting to) implement lexicographical ordering of lists.

Comment: "If length is not equal, return -1" Aside from that contradicting what you previously said, it's also wrong: the contract of `Comparator` requires that `sgn(cmp(a,b)) = -sgn(cmp(b,a))`. Hence, you can't always return -1 if their lengths differ.

Comment: Ur right, I saw that and forgot to change it. Thanks!

Comment: Also: "`if (o1.get(i) != o2.get(i)) {`" doesn't do what you mean.

Comment: You are totally right. Maybe I just rushed a bit to post the solution without correctly checking it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should [edit] your answer then.